# Does Omnipay uses Website Payment Pro or Paypal Payments Pro?

Tags: omnipay, website-payment-pro

I just read [Paypal's documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#wpp) and I'm seriously confused. It says that **'Website Payments Pro is a legacy product and has been replaced by PayPal Payments Pro'**

Now when I discovered Omnipay I was certain that website payments pro and paypal payments pro were the same thing. Now I'm confused as which one I'm using, and if there's any relevant difference between the two? Is it possible that on a near future Paypal will stop supporting Website Payments Pro?

*Ps: Now that I'm finished writing the question I'm doubting if it should be asked here. It's not a programming question per se, though the answer could be what programing differences are there between the two services. In either case, I'm terrible sorry if my question doesn't belong here, and please let me now so I can delete it.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. It is a vendor-specific support question and should be addressed to the vendor directly. (It also seems to contain it's own answer: *Website Payments Pro is a legacy product and has been replaced by PayPal Payments Pro'* seems clear. PayPal Payments Pro replaces Website Payments and if Omnipay currently uses Website Payments Pro they will have to switch at some point.

Comment: @KenWhite understood! Sorry for the trouble. Should I wait for question to be closed, or should I delete it?